# CMMotionManager - How to detect steps ignoring small movements?

Tags: ios, game-physics, cmmotionmanager

Getting data from the **`CMMotionManager`** is fairly straight forward, processing it not so much.

Does anybody have any pointers to code for relatively accurately detecting a step (and ignoring smaller movements) or guidelines in a general direction how to go about such a thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you basically need is a kind of a **Low Pass Filter** that will allow you to ignore small movements. Effectively, this “smooths” out the data by taking out the jittery.

```
- (void)updateViewsWithFilteredAcceleration:(CMAcceleration)acceleration
{
    static CGFloat x0 = 0;
    static CGFloat y0 = 0;

    const NSTimeInterval dt = (1.0 / 20);
    const double RC = 0.3;
    const double alpha = dt / (RC + dt);

    CMAcceleration smoothed;
    smoothed.x = (alpha * acceleration.x) + (1.0 - alpha) * x0;
    smoothed.y = (alpha * acceleration.y) + (1.0 - alpha) * y0;

    [self updateViewsWithAcceleration:smoothed];

    x0 = smoothed.x;
    y0 = smoothed.y;
}
```

The `alpha` value determines how much weight to give the previous data vs the raw data.
The `dt` is how much time elapsed between samples.
`RC` value controls the aggressiveness of the filter. Bigger values mean smoother output.

Comment: Oh yeah, time to brush up on my signal processing. Thanks, this clears stuff up a lot already.

Comment: For those looking to get acceleration information without the physical shaking of someone's hand (for example), you might actually be looking for `CMMotionManager.deviceMotion.gravity`.